# How to replace < and > symbols in a file with \< and \> respectively with sed inside Jenkins Groovy?

Tags: sed, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a file named body.txt which contains the following:

```
    <table><tr><td>Hello</td><td>World</td></tr></table>
```

I want to put \ in front of each < and > so that the file body.txt contains the following:

```
    \<table\>\<tr\>\<td\>Hello\</td\>\<td\>World\</td\>\</tr\>\</table\>
```

I am trying to do this from inside a Jenkins Groovy script.
I tried the following approaches:

Approach 1:

```
        sh "sed -i 's/</\\</g' body.txt"
        sh "sed -i 's/</\\</g' body.txt"
```

Approach 2:

```
        sh '''
        #!bin/bash
        sed -i "s/</\\</g" body.txt
        sed -i "s/>/\\>/g" body.txt
        '''
```

Approach 3:

```
        env.lt="<"
        env.lts="\\<"
        env.gt=">"
        env.gts="\\>"
    
        sh '''
        #!bin/bash
        sed -i "s/${lt}/${lts}/g" body.txt
        sed -i "s/${gt}/${gts}/g" body.txt
        '''
```

Approach 4:

```
        env.lt="<"
        env.lts="\\<"
        env.gt=">"
        env.gts="\\>"
    
        sh "sed -i 's/${lt}/${lts}/g' body.txt"
        sh "sed -i 's/${gt}/${gts}/g' body.txt"
```

Approach 5:

```
        sh "cat body.txt |tr '<' '\\<' > body1.txt"
        sh "cat body1.txt|tr '>' '\\>' > body2.txt"
        sh "cp body2.txt body.txt"
        sh "rm body1.txt body2.txt"
```

None of these approaches are working.
I am not getting any error, but replacement of < and > symbols are not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below command worked for me that ran inside Jenkins Groovy declarative pipeline script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat body.txt | awk '{gsub (/>/,"\\\\>");print}' | awk '{gsub (/</,"\\\\<");print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. You need to use `gsub` in `awk` to be able to perform the replacement. You also need to put two of `\` when you need to replace e.g. `>` with `\>`.

```
cat body.txt | awk '{gsub (/>/,"\\>");print}' | awk '{gsub (/</,"\\<");print}'
```

Another way using `sed` :

```
cat body.txt | sed 's,>,\\>,g' | sed 's,<,\\<,g'
```

Comment: `cat body.txt | awk '{gsub (/>/,"\\>");print}' | awk '{gsub (/</,"\\<");print}'` should be written as just  `awk '{gsub (/[<>]/,"\\&");print}' body.txt`. Similarly for sed - you don't need a UUOC and a pipe of multiple commands.